# Problems with snap applications. Libraries exited abnormally

Tags: 22.04, snap

This is the log related to Chromium

```
01:03:47 desktop-launch: /snap/chromium/2168/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libthai.so.0: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned
01:03:47 desktop-launch: /snap/chromium/2168/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libthai.so.0: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned
01:03:47 desktop-launch: ERROR: compile_giomodules /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu exited abnormally with status 127
01:03:47 desktop-launch: ERROR: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127
01:03:47 desktop-launch: ERROR: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders exited abnormally with status 127
01:03:47 gtk-query-immod: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: error while loading shared libraries: libthai.so.0: ELF load command address/offset not properly aligned
01:03:47 gdk-pixbuf-quer: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: error while loading shared libraries: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
01:03:47 kernel: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-querymodules: error while loading shared libraries: /snap/chromium/2168/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
01:03:47 5: update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib/snapd": permission denied
01:03:47 systemd: Started snap.chromium.chromium.61bb46c4-f534-4cb6-99f6-e2d7d1df46ea.scope.
```

Chromium is not started. The similar problems are seen with Firefox and Snap-Store. The .deb applications (like Midnight Commander) work normally. Solution is rebooting the computer. Snap applications work again after reboot.

sudo snap services

```
Service                                              Startup  Current  Notes
cups.cups-browsed                                    enabled  active   -
cups.cupsd                                           enabled  active   -
snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration  enabled  -        user
```

I am using 22.04.1 (Jammy).

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded kernel to 5.17.0-1020-oem. This helped. I had kernel 6.0.0-1006-oem.

Comment: Glad that you managed to figure it out. Could you please explain how you downgraded the kernel and how did this solve your issue. This would help the viewers understand the answer.

Comment: I found useful information on snapcraft.io forum. They submitted official bug report to kernel developers. Unfortunately, I can't find link to forum topic. Then, I simply had chosen previous kernel 5.17.0-1020-oem from grub menu. And the problem with snap applications disappeared. I have installed 5.17.0-1021-oem today. I think it will work normally with snaps since 1021 is security update.